# Scalar-values function in select making a huge difference in performance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sqlperformance

I'm using SQL Server 2008. I have a scalar values function to grab the time zone of a client and output the datetime as client timezone. I'm using it in a select statement in a stored procedure. I notice that using the function or not makes a huge difference in performance, I tried to check the execution plan and run the stored procedure with "statistics time, IO on" to check what is making the difference.

For example, this is the query with timezone adjustment:

```
Declare @ClientID int
Select @ClientID = 123

select 
    abt.someID, myDB..adjustTimeZone(@ClientID, abt.dtDate)
from 
    aBigTable as abt
where 
    abt.dtDate > '2016-08-01'
    and abt.dtDate < '2016-08-30'
```

Above code will return about 16k records and takes 16 secs to finish.

I clone the records to September just to make sure it is not because of any caching, then I use another way to adjust timezone, like the query below:

```
Declare @ClientID int, @ZoneHourChange int
select @ClientID = 123

select @ZoneHourChange = (select hourOffSet from Client 
                          where ClientID = @ClientID)

select 
    abt.someID, DateADD(hour, @ZoneHourChange, abt.dtDate)
from 
    aBigTable as abt
where 
    abt.dtDate > '2016-09-01'
    and abt.dtDate < '2016-09-30'
```

Above code returns 16k records also, but only takes half of the time. I can see from the execution plan, the cost is the same, and there is no parallelism involved. What leads to the huge difference? Thank you in advance.

Comment: one does a lookup for every row.. the other doesn't

Comment: Do you mean that the function will lookup the timezone information in the Client table for every row?

Comment: yes..  http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3845381/T-SQL-Best-Practices-150-Don146t-Use-Scalar-Value-Functions-in-Column-List-or-WHERE-Clauses.htm

Comment: Thank you. It is a good article, I never thought using view instead of function

Answer (score 0):

Scalar functions are something one should avoid if possible...

It can speed up your query enormously, if you change your function to an `inline TVF` returning a table with one single column.

Try this: Both functions seem to do the same, but the inline TVF performs much better...

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TestScalar()
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 'test';
END
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TestInlineTVF()
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN SELECT 'test' AS Result;
GO

SELECT dbo.TestScalar();

SELECT Result FROM TestInlineTVF();
GO

DROP FUNCTION dbo.TestInlineTVF;
DROP FUNCTION dbo.TestScalar;
```

Answer (score 0):

(Can you include the code for the function?)

If it's a `SELECT <return> FROM table WHERE cols = @params` then you're running that query once for every row being returned, and you'd probably be better off skipping the function and just adding the table as a join in your main query.